# Programmatically get access_token from OAuth - Using JIRA-Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, session, oauth, jira

I'm trying to write a JIRA-ruby script (only be used from command-line) to mark some JIRA issue closed automatically.

I borrow an example from [here](https://github.com/trineo/jira-ruby/blob/master/example.rb) because I'm using 'jira-ruby' gem.

This works however it will pop-up a browser asking you to click "Allow" to get the access_token.  I would like to do this programmatically, but I don't think the API was built for this purpose. As access_token changes every time, and this script will run periodically in a cronjob, so we need to have a way to do this.  Any idea what other ways we can do this?

```
require 'jira'

@jira = JIRA::Client.new({:site => 'http://localhost:2990', :context_path => '/jira', :consumer_key => 'test-jira', :private_key_file => "rsakey.pem"})

if ARGV.length == 0
  # If not passed any command line arguments, open a browser and prompt the
  # user for the OAuth verifier.
  request_token = @jira.request_token
  puts "Opening #{request_token.authorize_url}"
  system "open #{request_token.authorize_url}"

  puts "Enter the oauth_verifier: "
  oauth_verifier = gets.strip

  access_token = @jira.init_access_token(:oauth_verifier => oauth_verifier)
  puts "Access token: #{access_token.token} secret: #{access_token.secret}"
elsif ARGV.length == 2
  # Otherwise assume the arguments are a previous access token and secret.
  access_token = @jira.set_access_token(ARGV[0], ARGV[1])
else
  # Script must be passed 0 or 2 arguments
  raise "Usage: #{$0} [ token secret ]"
end

# Show all projects
projects = @jira.Project.all

projects.each do |project|
  puts "Project -> key: #{project.key}, name: #{project.name}"
end
issue = @jira.Issue.find('DEMO-1')
puts issue
```

I know there's a way to use long-life access tokens, but not really use if Jira supports it.

Comment: Hello xbeta. I want your help for same. I want to make CLI with access token. can you give me detail description how can I make it?

Answer (score -1):

I was using the jira-ruby gem at first but I found the performance terrible.  I ended up just going with curl instead as I only needed to require the JSON gem which is less bloated.  Have your Jira administrators create a user that will never have the password change with admin access and then do the following to find "DEMO-1"

```
require 'json'

username = "admin"
password = "abc123"

issue = JSON.parse(%x[curl -u #{username}:#{password} \"http://jira/rest/api/latest/issue/DEMO-1\"])
```

Here is a [link to the Jira REST API documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/), just choose the same version of Jira you are using.  This will bypass any issues with oauth and the pop-up.

Comment: Thanks! But I prefer not to use single account. We want to write a tool which lets all of our devs to use OAuth login and performing JIRA task under their own accounts which can show up in the history.